# Help with white-space: nowrap and normal in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, whitespace

I can not figure this out...

I have a div called '#ContentContainer' and it's width is 100% and it needs a white-space of nowrap so it's innards which expand and collapse will venture outside the window and create a horizontal scroll.  Within the expanding and collapsing divs, I have text and images.  In IE, these inner divs have the white-space: nowrap applied to them... I've set the white-space to normal, but IE doesn't recognize that.. can anyone help?

Here CSS:

```
#ContentContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.column {
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 220px;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="#ContentContainer">
    <div class="column">
        Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  Text that needs to have a white-space or normal.  It needs to wrap.  
    </div>

</div>
```

Anyone?

Comment: I have the same problem and have not yet found any solution. Unfortunately many misunderstand the question: it's _not_ that white-space:nowrap; doesn't work, but that once set it _keeps_on_ working for all descendants with seemingly no way to cancel it (at least in IE8).

Answer (score 3):

The `white-space:nowrap` property is supported in all versions of IE, so this should work just fine for you.

Your problem is not your CSS, but an error in your HTML: You have `<div id="#ContentContainer">`, but this is incorrect: the ID in the HTML code should not contain the hash symbol (`#`). It is required in the CSS code to *reference* an ID, but the ID itself should not contain it.

So your CSS is correct as it is:

```
#ContentContainer {
   ....
}
```

but your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="ContentContainer">
    ....
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery finally solved after almost three weeks: Seeming to parse and cascade the CSS instruction `white-space:normal;` correctly, but not *really* doing anything with it (thus effectively making white-space:nowrap; immortal) was a bug in IE 5.5. Later versions of IE that get into some sort of "compatibility mode" or "quirks mode" may repeat this misbehavior. Its appearance is affected by both the exact version of IE and the contents of the DOCTYPE -and even intranet vs. internet (which explains why it doesn't show up at all for many people, and why so many answers don't seem to make much sense).

The *sure* way to get rid of this misbehavior is to force all versions of IE to use a more recent rendering model (the examples below use "the latest rendering model that each version is capable of"), which requires sending them the `X-UA-Compatible` HTTP header, either from the web server if possible, or inside each relevant document as a fallback. For the Apache server, the command to add to .htaccess is something similar to

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
```

For PHP it should simply be addition of a couple lines of code, and for IIS it should simply be a config addition. (You could also experiment with the optimizations of sending this header only with HTML files and/or sending it only to IE browsers.)

If you can't change the server's behavior, the fallback is to add in the <head> of each relevant file *before **all** Javascript or CSS* something similar to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```